# VHDL: Should it be possible to aggregate multiple events in the process?

Tags: vhdl

have the following code

```
process(clk1, clk2)is
    begin
    if(clk1'event and clk1 = '1')then
    --code 1;
    elsif(clk2'event and clk2 = '1')then
    --code 2;
    end if;
    end process;
```

I use Xilinx Compositor, specifically Xilinx ISE 14.7:

Is the above code any good to aggregate multiple events?

I read in "Synthesis and Simulation UG626" there is no direction similar to my code.

Comment: Not likely. Note the test for the second edge test is dependent on not being coincident with the first edge. An if statement with additional evaluated conditions is a priority encoder. The first true condition's statements are exclusively executed.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it in vhdl as a language. But you're unlikely to find a tool that allows it as a synthesisable construct as no hardware exists that can prioritize one clock over another.

Comment: You'd find FPGA synthesis has more restrictions than other platforms. The definitive guide is the withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis standard 6.1.3.3 Edge-sensitive storage with one or more clocks. That contains "Multiple if statements with different clock edge conditions may be used to update a signal or variable inside a process." and "The clock edge conditions shall be mutually exclusive." You have a single if statement. The -2004 standard was withdrawn due to lack of vendor participation, allowing vendor lock-in in outlier situations. This isn't one of them.

Comment: The -2004 standard 1.1 Scope "This standard defines a subset of very high-speed integrated circuit hardware description language (VHDL) that ensures portability of VHDL descriptions between register transfer level synthesis tools. Synthesis tools may be compliant and yet have features beyond those required by this standard." 6.1.3.3 was a point of contention between FPGA vendors who generally restrict dual clock edge processes to inferring DDR using I/O cells.

Comment: @user16145658:  I agree.  Clearly 1076.6-2004 shows your code as something vendors should support.   To support your code though there needs to be a corresponding cell that is valid to map.   For some FPGA's that may be only in the IO.

Comment: Where's the two if statements in the question?  Also note the two conditions can only be mutually exclusive if the two clocks are related and guaranteed to not be coincidental. Further It's not my code and I didn't claim it should be supported or is synthesis eligible.

Answer (score 3):

First 1076.6-2004, says this coding style can be used to target things like DDR IO cells and Dual Port RAM/ROM.

1076.6-2004 shows a register with two clocks being created using this sort of coding style in clause 6.1.3.3, page 14, Example 1 - note though that this coding style is more similar to what should be usable for a dual port RAM:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.Std_Logic_1164.all;
entity multi_clock_ff_example is
port(
  reset, clk1, clk2, data1, data2 : in Std_Logic;
  Q                               : out Std_Logic );
end;
architecture RTL of multi_clock_ff_example is
begin
  -- Process sensitive to controlling signals reset, clk1 and clk2
  process( reset, clk1, clk2 )
  begin
    if reset = '1' then
      Q <= '0' ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk1) then
      Q <= data1 ;
    elsif rising_edge(clk2) then
      Q <= data2 ;
    end if ;
    . . .
  end process ;
end architecture RTL ;
```

So in your "code 1" and "code 2", to target either DDR IO cells and Dual Port RAM/ROM, they need to be interacting with either the same register or same RAM/ROM.

As @tricky and @user16XXX said if there is not a corresponding cell in the library, then expect the tool to generate errors.

Said in another way, do not mix unrelated items in "code 1" and "code 2", particularly from two different clock domains.   Clock domain crossings are hard to get right anyway.

As @tricky mentioned, some vendors do not like this code because the code has priority in it.

Yet the same vendors often support synthesis of dual port RAMS using separate processes and shared variables of an ordinary type, such as the following, which also has priority in it:

```
architecture RTL of DPRam_SV_RIRO_RF_64k is
  type MemType is array (0 to 2**16-1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) ;
  shared variable Mem : MemType ;
begin
  MemProcA : process (ClkA) 
  begin
    if rising_edge(ClkA) then     
      DataOutA <= Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrA))) ; 
      if WriteA = '1' then 
        Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrA))) := DataInA ; 
      end if ;
    end if ;
  end process MemProcA ;

  MemProcB : process (ClkB) 
  begin 
    if rising_edge(ClkB) then     
      DataOutB <= Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrB))) ; 
      if WriteB = '1' then 
        Mem(to_integer(unsigned(AddrB))) := DataInB ; 
      end if ;
    end if ;
  end process MemProcB ;
end RTL ;
```

The priority is still here, it is just not deterministic - the last process that runs and does an assignment to the shared variable has priority.   In addition, usage of shared variables of an ordinary type is illegal - they were deprecated and removed from the language in VHDL-2002.

Hence, if you are targeting either DDR IO cells or Dual Port RAM/ROM, please file a bug report with your vendor.   It may help of you cite supporting information here and in my blog post:  [VHDL: Shared Variables, Protected Types, and Memory Modeling](https://osvvm.org/archives/1758)

Comment: *First 1076.6-2004, says your code is correct.* Citation please. The two clocks haven't been shown to be mutually exclusive nor does the OP use two if statements. As far as your dual port memory the OP does not specify the sequence of statements where the two comments -- code 1 and -- code 2 are shown. The question is not a specific programming problem which would require a [mcve] and a deterministic result not guaranteed to be correctly provided following synthesis which the OP doesn't claim to have been attempted.

Comment: @user16145658  I added my citation in the post for a two clock flip-flop.   WRT semantics, last executed assignment wins.   So whether an "if-then-elsif-then-elsif", an "if-end if; - if-end if", or two separate processes are used with a shared variable, there is still priority involved.   Hence, you have to decide to be pragmatic and ask, is there anything useful I can do with the coding styles.   Certainly synthesis vendors have taken this route when they decided to support shared variables of an ordinary type - even though it is deprecated and removed from the language.

Comment: There is no way for the code to express that the clocks are mutually exclusive - instead that is a necessary assumption for a synthesis vendor to make to properly interpret the code.

Comment: Here you need the OP to supply more information to determine if RTL of multi_clock_ff_example matches the unknown usage in the question (those pesky comments -- code 1 and -- code2). No where does the OP address DDR nor is your assumption clk1 and clk2 rising edges are mutually exclusive supported in the question without DDR. Get the question clarified.

Comment: I guess we live in different worlds as instead of pestering the OP, I framed up where it is legal and demonstrated it.  WRT my assumption about mutual exclusion, I worked on 1076.6-2004 including this part, so I do have some unique insight into interpreting it - see page iv.   No where in the standard does it require the user code to prove mutual exclusion.  Instead the synthesis tool uses that information to produce a circuit.

Comment: Indeed we live in different worlds [The use of set_clock_groups informs the system of the relationship between specific clock domains. By default, the clock domains are all synchronous and related to each other. If your design has clock domains that are asynchronous to each other, then you need to use the set_clock_groups command.](https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/44651?language=en_US). This requires the tool user to notify the tool if the clocks are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yet they do not require this for their dual port RAM code which is similar in semantics to this.   Sadly their code is illegal in VHDL.   I should also add that they did not participate in 1076.6 and apparently have interpreted it differently than intended.